# How to search Keywords like IN, OR, AND in a column with FullText Index in MSSQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I want to search keywords like IN, OR, etc from a table with Fulltext index like this:

```
SELECT * from Table1 where
CONTAINS(countrycode, 'IN OR DE OR GB')
```

But this query is returning the rows with "DE" or "GB" only, not "IN". How this can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because IN and OR are keywords on SQL.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx:

> B. Using CONTAINS and phrase in
>
> The following example returns all
>   products that contain either the
>   phrase "Mountain" or "Road".
>
> Copy USE AdventureWorks2008R2; GO
>   SELECT Name FROM Production.Product
>   WHERE CONTAINS(Name, ' "Mountain" OR
>   "Road" ')

Comment: True, But it doesn't work for SELECT Name FROM Production.Product WHERE CONTAINS(Name, ' "IN" OR "ABCD" '). This will return rows having ABCD only..

Comment: That's because IN is probably considered a stop word in your configuration (which is the default behaviour).See the SQL Server contains reference. Your best bet may be to use the SQL IN() operator to do what you're trying to do, and reserve the use of contains for other scenarios.

Comment: You have to remove IN as a stop word though, if you want to IN to be included. If there are other words you want to work with your query, you'll have to ensure that those are not stop words as well.